# How to map oracle dataType to java dataType?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, type-conversion

how can mapping oracle dataType to java dataType?

I tried as below but Not accurate .

```
 DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = this.getConnection().getMetaData(); 
 ResultSet rs = databaseMetaData.getColumns(catalog, schema, tableName, columnName);

 while (rs.next()) {
     if ( rs.getString("data_type").equals(Types.NUMERIC)){
           javaDataType = "java.math.BigDecimal";
     } }
```

for example :
oracle => number(2,3) => javaDataType = BigDecimal;
oracle => number(15) => javaDataType = BigDecimal;

Best way to convert oracle `dataType` to java `dataType`?

Answer (score 10):

I am not quite sure what are you trying to do.
Oracle has default mappings between java clases and SQL types, 
please take a look at this table: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28906

For example there are valid conversions from a `NUMBER` type to java types:

```
+---------------+--------------------+
| SQL data type | Java types         |
+---------------+--------------------+
|   NUMBER      |boolean             |
|               |char                |   
|               |byte                |
|               |short               |
|               |int                 |
|               |long                |
|               |float               |
|               |double              |
|               |java.lang.Byte      |
|               |java.lang.Short     |
|               |java.lang.Integer   |
|               |java.lang.Long      |
|               |java.lang.Float     |
|               |java.lang.Double    |
|               |java.math.BigDecimal|
|               |oracle.sql.NUMBER   |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

If we want to get a `NUMBER` as a specific java type, we need to use an appriopriate `getXXX` method from the `ResultSet` interface, for example:
**getInt** retrieves the number as java int--> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29

**getLong** retrieves the number as java long --> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getLong%28int%29

**getDouble** retrieves the number as java long --> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDouble%28int%29

**getBigDecimal** retrieves the number as java BigDecimal --> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBigDecimal%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

This is your - the developer - responsibility to choose the proper method for your data.

Comment: I want to map "DATA TYPE" appear in "ORACEL" to exact "DATA TYPE" in "JAVA" soure code for instance "NUMBER(13,2)" to "FLOAT" by distinguishing in source code.

Comment: Your sentiments do not work for JPA/Hibernate.